# What does "in use by" mean for Google Cloud VM's

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

When I look at VM instances in my Google Cloud console I see a column "in use by"

I see two VM instances (e,g vm-a and vm-b) "in use by"  vm-c  . I also see an instance template say template-1 and that to has "in use by" vm-c.  But I'm confused I cannot see vm-c in my VM's listed in Google Cloud console and I have no idea what "in use by" refers to, so can someone tell me how this all fits together ?

Thanks

I have googled the documentation but the explanation is not clear

Comment: This is an example where a screenshot is helpful.

Comment: Sorry I cannot supply a screenshot as its work related

Answer (score 0):

This may means that the 2 instances are currently being used as a source for creating other resources. for example, if vm-c is an instance template (template-1 in your case), then vm-a and vm-b are being used as the source configuration for that template. When you create new VMs from template-1, they will be based on the current configuration of vm-a and vm-b.

One reason may be that you don't have permission to view all vm instances. Some vm instances might be assigned to specific projects or folders that you don't have access.

You can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/labeling-resources) as reference.